# Joint density function (exercise)

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I'd like to know if the following is correct. Thank you.

Consider the following function $f(x,y)=K(x+xy+y)\, \chi_{(x,y)\in [0,1]^2}(x,y)$, where $K$ is a constant and $\chi_A$ is the indicator function.

> i) Find a $K$ such that $f_{X,Y} =f$ is the joint density of two random variables $X$ and $Y$
>
> ii) Find the joint distribution function of  $F_{X,Y}$ of $X$ and $Y$
>
> iii) Find the marginals distributions $F_X$ and $F_Y$
>
> iv) Find the marginals densities $f_X$ and $f_Y$
>
> v) Find $E(X),\operatorname{Var} (X)$ and respectively for $Y$ and also find the covariance of $X$ and $Y$
>
> vi) Are $X$ and $Y$ independent random variables?

**Proof**:  For $i)$ we need to find $K$ such that $\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} f(x,y) d(\lambda\times\lambda) =1$. Since $f$ is $\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R}^2)$-measurable and non-negative function we can use the Tonelli's thm and so

\begin{align*}\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} f(x,y) d(\lambda\times\lambda)=\int_\mathbb{R} \left(\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x,y) dx \right) dy&=\int_0^1\int_0^1 K(x+xy+y)dxdy\\
&=5K/4\end{align*}

Therefore $K=4/5$.

For ii) Letting $F(x,y)=\int_{A(x,y)} f(x,y) d(\lambda \times \lambda)$, where $A(x,y)=\{(w,v)\in \mathbb{R}^2:w\le x \text{ and } v\le y\}$, $F$ is the distribution function of the random variables $X$ and $Y$. To obtain explicitly $F$, we have

$$F(x,y)=\begin{cases} 0 & \text{if $x<0$ or $y<0$ }\\
\frac{4}{5} (x^2y/2+x^2y^2/4+xy^2/2) &\text{if $(x,y)\in [0,1]^2$}\\
\frac{4}{5} (3x^2/4+x/2) &\text{if $y>1$ and $x\in [0,1]$}\\
\frac{4}{5} (3y^2/4+y/2) &\text{if $x>1$ and $y\in [0,1]$}\\
1 &\text{if $x>1$ and $y>1$}
 \end{cases}$$

iii) By symmetry it will sufficient to find  $F(x)=\lim_{y\to \infty} F(x,y)$. Then we have

$$F(x)=\begin{cases} 0 & \text{if $x<0$ or $y<0$ }\\
\frac{4}{5} (3x^2/4+x/2) &\text{if $y>1$ and $x\in [0,1]$}\\
1 &\text{if $x>1$ and $y>1$}
 \end{cases}$$

The other marginal distribution is the same as above only interchanging $x$ to $y$.

iv) Let $f(x)=\frac{4}{5} (3x/2+1/2)\chi _{[0,1]}$, then clearly $\int_{(-\infty,x]} f(x) d\lambda=F(x)$ for all $x$ in $\mathbb{R}$ and a similar result follows for $f(y)$ (only changing each $x$ for $y$).

v) $E(x)=\int X dP=\int x f(x) \lambda(dx) = 3/5$, now $E(X^2)=\int x^2 f(x) \lambda(dx)=13/30$, so easily follows that $\operatorname{var} (X) =11/150$. Notice by symmetry the same values are for $Y$. Now for the covariance, let $g$ be the product (which trivially is a Borel measurable function since is continuous) then we have

\begin{align*}  E(XY)=\int XY dP=\int g((X,Y)) dP =\int g(x,y) dP_{X,Y}=\int xy dP_{X,Y} \tag{*}\end{align*}

Now since $P_{X,Y}$ is absolutely continuous with respect to $\lambda \times \lambda$ and $f=f_{X,Y}= dP_{X,Y}/d (\lambda\times \lambda)$ almost everywhere, then for the Radon-Nikodym chain rule and the Fubini-Tonelli' theorem (since $\int_{\mathbb{R^2}} |xy f| d(\lambda\times \lambda)<\infty$) we have in $(*)$ the following

\begin{align*}  E(XY)=\int xy dP_{X,Y} =\int_{\mathbb{R^2}} xy f d(\lambda\times \lambda)&=\int_\mathbb{R} \left( \int_{\mathbb{R}} xy f dx\right) dy\\
&=\int_{0}^1 \int_0^1 4/5xy(x+xy+y)dx dy=16/45\end{align*}

Therefore $\operatorname{cov}(X,Y)=E(XY)_E(X)E(Y)=16/45-9/25=-1/225\not=0$.

vi) No. If $X$ and $Y$ were independent then $\operatorname{cov}(X,Y)=0$ as $X$ and $Y$ are in $\mathscr{L}^1$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'd like to know if the following is correct.

Yes, in its entirety.   Do you have any particular doubts?

( Well, there are a few formatting errors, but typosh appen. )

Comment: First of all, thank you for answer the question and take your time for reading. Well I'm no completely sure on the deduction of a way to calculate $E(X,Y)$ using the joint density $f_{X,Y}$?

Comment: It is the very definition of expectation of the product of two continuous distributed random variables. @JoseAntonio

Comment: Thank you again. Let me see if a understand. Let $Z=(X,Y)$ the random vector and let $g$, the function $(x,y)\longmapsto x\cdot y$, then $g$ is Borel measurable and so $g\circ Z$ is a random variable (composition of measurable is measurable). Then $E|g\circ Z|=\int_{\Omega} |g\circ Z| dP=\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} |g| dP_Z=\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} |xy| dP_z$, now since $P_Z<<\lambda^2$, and using the chain rule for the R-N- thm we have $E|g\circ Z|=\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} |xy| f d\lambda^2$

Comment: now since $(x,y)\longmapsto|xy|f(x,y)$ is a non-negative measurable function, the Tonelli's thm give us that $\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} |xy| f d\lambda^2=\int_{\mathbb{R}} \left(\int_{\mathbb{R}} |x||y| f(x,y) \lambda (dx)\right) \lambda(dy)<\infty$, therefore using the Fubini's thm we have $E(XY)=\int_{\mathbb{R}} \left(\int_{\mathbb{R}} x\cdot y\, f(x,y) \lambda (dx)\right) \lambda(dy)$

Comment: Is for the above argument the reason, for what we calculate the E(X,Y) in that way?